# LaTeX is crossing its limits

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking

Pardon for the funny title. I have a large report in the middle of which there is a sentence

```
Let $\mathcal{L}$ : $\mathcal{O}$ $\rightarrow$ $\mathcal{S}$ be a function
```

This shows in the report as in the third line of the following image. 
[image: L:O->S]
Now I want the function declaration `L:O->S` to be in one line. Can anything be done?

Also, there is another line in the report

```
For example, a square lattice has the security classes, $\mathcal{S}$ = \{\textit{Unclassified},\textit{$Secret_1$},\textit{$Secret_2$},\textit{Top Secret}\}.
```

This line shows in the report like this

[image: S={U,S1,S2,TS}]

I don't want `S = {Unclassified, Secret1, Secret2, Top Secret}` to go beyond the margins. MWE for this problem is:

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
For example, a square lattice has the security classes, $\mathcal{S}$ = \{\textit{Unclassified},\textit{$Secret_1$},\textit{$Secret_2$},\textit{Top Secret}\}.
\end{document}
```

Can anything be done?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Try \[ \mathcal{L} \colon \mathcal{O} \to \mathcal{S} \], to get the correct spacing around the colon.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer By one line, I meant not to be broken into two lines. Rather like this: Blah blah `L:O->S` blah. I could have given it multiple spaces so that it completely shifts to next line but LaTeX would take that as a single space.

Comment: First of all, you shouldn't use math like that, then Latex doesn't space it correctly. Instead `$\mathcal{L} \colon \mathcal{O} \to \mathcal{S}$` (the `\colon` is just a `:` with punctuation spacing). As for the second: `$\mathcal{S} = \{\textit{Unclassified},$ $\textit{Secret}_1,$ $\textit{Secret}_2,$ $\textit{Top Secret}\}$`. This doesn't answer your question, but is an improvement, I think.

Comment: You could simply put an `\allowbreak` after every comma in the list, say, `\textit{foo},\allowbreak\textit{bar}...` `:)`

Comment: @KamalBanga No, that wasn't meant to be a solution. I think you misuse the math environment and that was a suggestion about how I would use it. I tried nothing about your problems.

Comment: @Manuel I am talking about the second problem. Spaces after commas allow line breaks so now it doesn't cross the margins.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Avoiding line breaks in inline formulae

For the first problem, it maybe requires a little rearranging/rephrasing.

You can for example rephrase the previous sentence so it is a little longer and the formula (along with its introducing "Let") gets pushed into the next line.

Another option, as suggested in the comments, is to turn the formula into a displayed one by replacing the `$` pair with `\[` and `\]`.

There is a third solution which is: forcing it to be unbreakable wrapping it with a `\mbox`, or inserting ad-hoc line-breaks. I do not recommend doing this is the other options can work **and** if you do choose this one consider doing it *only when the text is stable* and only needing finishing touches. This is because if later changes remove the need for the manual adjustments you may end up with a suboptimal or plain wrong layout.

## Commas not breaking lines in math mode

The second problem is caused by the fact that commas in math mode do not mark a point where you can break a line.
To solve this I use the following macro:

```
\mathchardef\breakingcomma\mathcode`\,
{\catcode`,=\active
  \gdef,{\breakingcomma\discretionary{}{}{}}
}
\newcommand{\commabr}[1]{\mathcode`\,=\string"8000 #1}
```

It is a bit complicated to explain but it defines a command `\commabr` which you can use to enclose regions of formulas where you want the comma to mark a "breakable point" (example: `$S = \{\commabr{\mathit{Unclassified}, \mathit{Secret1}, \mathit{Secret2}, \mathit{Top Secret}}\}$`)

Comment: I understand the second problem, so I think I will just give spaces after comma rather than using this macro. Thanks btw.

Comment: You don't need a `\mbox` to make inline math unbreakable: You can use a pair of braces: `${a=b=c=d}$`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I didn't know that! useful tip!

Comment: How can the `mbox` (or pair of braces) lead to suboptimal layout if the text changes in the future?

Comment: "Unclassified", et al., really should be set with either `\mathit` or `\textit`.  as it is, the letters in those words will be italic, but will have the spacing of variables.

Comment: @barbarabeeton absolutely, I just copied the example the OP gave verbatim focussing on showing how to use `\commabr`

Comment: @T.Verron what I mean is that, in general, suppose the text changes so that the linebreak would break what you put in the mbox but in an acceptable way. You would prevent that acceptable break and TeX would be forced to find other points for the break. I was trying to warn against the over-zealous use of mbox.

Answer (score 1):

The second problem can be solved by giving spaces next to comma. Like this:

```
$\mathcal{S}$ = \{\textit{Unclassified}, \textit{$Secret_1$}, \textit{$Secret_2$}, \textit{Top Secret}\}.
```

Comment: This is a fundamentally wrong approach. You should not be going in and out of math mode all the time; a single pair of dollars surrounding the whole formula should suffice. If you need additional break points inside the formula, there are ways to address that, but interrupting the formula thwarts TeX's attempts to generate proper spacing between symbols. If you prefer placing everything by hand, you shouldn't be using TeX in the first place; there are formula editors out there the will let you (actually force you) to do that.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Ok. So I think I should do something like `\textit{foo},\allowbreak\textit{bar}... `.